# how to show the records that includes NaN values in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

I have a GUI interface using pyqt5 in python that create a window that allow the user to load a csv file and work on it as print the headers and make functions one of these functions is display the records that includes  NaN values.

when i press this button the system crash and display the below error :

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'isna'
```

## GUI part :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
          self.setObjectName("Form")
          self.setEnabled(True)
          self.resize(533, 575)
        
          self.display_nan_values = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
          self.display_nan_values.setObjectName("display_nan_values")
          self.display_nan_values.clicked.connect(self.print_df_NaN)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      ui = Ui_Form()
      ui.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## function code:

```
   def print_df_NaN(self,df):
        print(self.df[df.isna().any(axis=1)])
```

where is the error in this function ?

where as if i write this function below it run but that is not what i want.

```
def print_df_NaN(self,df):
        print(self.df.isna())
```

the result is :

```
    event_type   date  event_city  event_location  number_person  groups
0          False  False       False           False          False   False
1          False  False       False           False          False   False
2          False  False       False           False          False   False
3          False  False       False           False          False   False
4          False  False       False           False          False   False
...          ...    ...         ...             ...            ...     ...
3377       False  False       False           False          False   False
3378       False  False       False           False          False   False
3379       False  False       False           False          False   False
3380       False  False       False           False          False   False
3381       False  False       False           False          False   False
```

based on answer @leminhnguyenHUST i updated the function :

```
def print_df_NaN(self,df):
    def get_not_nan(self,df):
        for col in df.columns:
            df = df[~pd.isnull(df[col])]
        return df
    df1 = get_not_nan(df)
    print(df[~df.apply(tuple,1).isin(df1.apply(tuple,1))])
```

Comment: Isn't `df.fillna()` what you need? that fills `NaN`s with value

Comment: no because if a column not required or it can be droped  the next step is to drop the record

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['thg', 'thg', 'mol', 'mol', 'lob', 'lob'],'rating': [3., 4., 5., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],'name': ['John','James', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan]})

def get_nan_rows(df1):
    def get_not_nan(df):
        for col in df.columns:
            df = df[~pd.isnull(df[col])]
        return df
    df2 = get_not_nan(df1)
    return df1[~df1.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1))]

get_nan_rows(df1)
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: i tried your answer but it give this error :`  df1 = get_not_nan(df)
TypeError: get_not_nan() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'`

i will edit my qyestion and add the updated function

Comment: @PylebPyl3b I've tried copy all my code and run again and It's working perfectly